# Default formatter being overridden by custom formatter

Tags: .net

I've made a custom formatter following the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2). My custom formatter writes out a response as a special kind of Byte Array, and it should be used when a request has "application/octet-stream" in it's "Accept" header.

I would like the default to just return a json object, like it does when it is called using "application/json", but instead it is defaulting to using my formatter when I do not specify a header. How do I fix this and just use the default JsonOutputFormatter?

I'm adding my formatter like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new OctetStreamOutputFormatter());
    });
}
```

Comment: I can add further details and more code if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the way to not override the default formatter is to Add to the end of the OutputFormatters instead of Inserting into the beginning of the list. This change worked:

I've made a custom formatter following the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2). My custom formatter writes out a response as a special kind of Byte Array, and it should be used when a request has "application/octet-stream" in it's "Accept" header.

I would like the default to just return a json object, like it does when it is called using "application/json", but instead it is defaulting to using my formatter when I do not specify a header. How do I fix this and just use the default JsonOutputFormatter?

I'm adding my formatter like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new OctetStreamOutputFormatter());
    });
}
```